# Telegram Bot Api: Chat_id is not accepted in forwardMessage Method

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to forward a message in telegram bot API. It shows "Bad Request: chat_id is empty" despite using same chat_id in sendMessage and works perfectly fine.

**Requested Method**

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/forwardMessage?chat_id={CHAT_ID}&from_chat_id={ID}&message_id={MID}
```

**Result:**

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: chat_id is empty"}
```

**Updates**

There is a reported bug for similar problem in sendPhoto and sendDocument at this [link](https://github.com/rainu/telegram-bot-api/issues/1).

Comment: Please show all the revelant code, including where `CHAT_ID` and `ID` come from.

Comment: I set these variable manually, but I am sure they are valid. You can find these variables in a JSON at getUpdates method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the information you're providing it's hard to tell what isn't working.
All i can say is that I can forward messages like this

```
$post = array("from_chat_id" => $from_chat, "chat_id" => $to_chat, "message_id" => $m_id);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/forwardMessage");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: your code doesn't work! Please try it your self then publish. It is not important to call a api function by url or php code. For simplicity, I remove unnecessary code and call it directly by url.

Comment: I'm using this code since several months and it works just fine

Comment: Yeap! I made a mistake in my message id and it is not matched with from_chat_id. Anyway, Thank @Maak.